# Is it possible to develop a plugin without an account?

Tags: newrelic-platform

We want to develop a plugin for NewRelic, but we'd like to do it separately from the company we work for (which is who owns the NewRelic commercial account)

Is it possible to develop it without an account (and thus, independently from a company) or is it 100% required to have the plugin belong to a company with a NewRelic account?

Comment: NewRelic has free accounts, would that be enough? Have you tried contacting NewRelic support or do you want to develop this plugin anonymously (no traceable connections between the plugin, you and the company you work for)?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö, no problem with traceability, I'd use my own name. I don't know if a free account is enough for developing a plugin, will check it out. As for contacting NR, I know they are monitoring this tag, it says so in their plugin docs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any New Relic account can consume, author, and publish plugins.

If you don't have an account, or want to publish from an account that is different from your primary or work account, simply signup for a new account - and if you do so via any of the plugin detail pages here http://www.newrelic.com/platform you'll get New Relic Standard for free, forever! (otherwise Standard is a paid tier, and Lite is free forever)